# unable to query database using timestamp

Tags: cassandra

I have this table

```
user_authentication_token (
    token_id uuid,
    user_id uuid,
    email text,
    expiration_time timestamp,
    is_sign_up boolean,
    PRIMARY KEY ((token_id, user_id, email, expiration_time))
```

and I have this data in the table

```
token_id                             | user_id                              | email                   | expiration_time                 | is_sign_up
--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+-------------------------+---------------------------------+------------
 98b0456a-05b2-4aca-a6c7-6a1f382e19aa | b284d51d-efbb-4204-b342-a2486029a5c5 | manu.chadha@hotmail.com | 2018-09-01 09:40:59.634000+0000 |       True
```

But I am unable to query it.

`select * from user_authentication_token where token_id=98b0456a-05b2-4aca-a6c7-6a1f382e19aa and user_id=b284d51d-efbb-4204-b342-a2486029a5c5 and email='manu.chadha@hotmail.com' and expiration_time='2018-09-01 09:40:59.634000+0000';`

Error - `InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="Unable to coerce '2018-09-01 09:40:59.634000+0000' to a formatted date (long)"`

What am I doing wrong?

I inserted the row using `Cassandra Java Datastax` driver and the following code

```
def insertValues(tableName:String, model:UserToken):Insert = {
    QueryBuilder.insertInto(tableName).value("token_id",model.tokenId) 
      .value("email",model.email)
      .value("user_id",model.userId)
      .value("expiration_time",model.expirationTime.getMillis())
      .value("is_sign_up",model.isSignUp)
      .ifNotExists(); }}
```

Interestingly, timestamp is stored as `long` but the `cqlsh` is showing it in a readable format. Probably I need to convert it into `long` again but how do I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your timestamp should include nothing beyond milliseconds:

```
select * from user_authentication_token
where token_id=98b0456a-05b2-4aca-a6c7-6a1f382e19aa
and user_id=b284d51d-efbb-4204-b342-a2486029a5c5
and email='manu.chadha@hotmail.com'
and expiration_time='2018-09-01 09:40:59.634+0000'; // removed extra precision
```

**Update:** Added timezone offset as discovered by Manu Chadha below.

Comment: Interesting, didn't get error but didn't get any data either! `select * from user_authentication_token where token_id=98b0456a-05b2-4aca-a6c7-6a1f382e19aa and user_id=b284d51d-efbb-4204-b342-a2486029a5c5 and email='manu.chadha@hotmail.com' and expiration_time='2018-09-01 09:40:59.634';

 token_id | user_id | email | expiration_time | is_sign_up
----------+---------+-------+-----------------+------------

(0 rows)`

Comment: this worked. I removed `000` as you suggested but I had to add timezone. Otherwise the value didn't match -`select * from user_authentication_token where  token_id=98b0456a-05b2-4aca-a6c7-6a1f382e19aa and user_id=b284d51d-efbb-4204-b342-a2486029a5c5 and email='manu.chadha@hotmail.com' and expiration_time='2018-09-01 09:40:59.634+0000';`

Comment: Updated the answer based on your findings.

Comment: addendum from the documentation `If no time zone is specified, the time zone of the Cassandra coordinator node handing the write request is used. For accuracy, DataStax recommends specifying the time zone rather than relying on the time zone configured on the Cassandra nodes.`